# Proof of Hausdorffness of sequentially Hausdorff space under its sequential topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, filters, nets

Under "Topology of sequentially open sets" section of the Wikipedia page [Sequential Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#T-sequential_and_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000106-QINU%60%22%27%7F-sequential_spaces), there is a claim which says

> any sequentially Hausdorff(i.e. every convergent sequence has a unique limit) space $(X,\tau)$, its sequential topology $\bar\tau=\{S\subset X|\text{SeqInt}_\tau S=S\}$ is Hausdorff(the space $(X,\bar\tau)$ is Hausdorff).

Proving the sequentially Hausdorffness of a space that has Hausdorff sequential topology is rather easy, since any sequence has the same convergence under its original topology and its sequential topology.
The trouble occurs to me when I try to prove the original claim. I transformed the original claim into proving $\exists p,q\in X(\forall U(\ni p)\in\bar\tau,q\in \text{Cl}_{\bar\tau}U)$ being false, my idea is to try constructing a sequence that converges to both $p,q$ under this condition, but I am unable to progress further.
Several examples(of co-countable topology) suggest me these $T_2$ non-separable(but $T_1$ separable) points would obtain discrete topology, does this still hold on other examples?

Comment: The sequential reflection of $X$ in the co-countable topology is the discrete topology on $X$ indeed, as all subsets are sequentially closed etc. So $X$ is sequentially Hausdorff *because* its reflection is indeed Hausdorff. It's a "positive" example of the claim as made by Wikipedia.

Comment: The cocountable topology happens to be US indeed, but that's a coincidence, as it were.

Comment: FYI, the confusing parts of that wikipedia page have since been removed.  See the discussion in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Sequential_space#Sequentially_Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page you cited actually **defines** $(X,\tau)$ to be sequentially Hausdorff iff $(X, \bar{\tau})$ is Hausdorff (in the usual sense).

The property that convergent sequences have unique limits (sometimes called US) is quite different, so the remark "sequentially Hausdorff(i.e. every convergent sequence has a unique limit)" is false. I cannot find it in that form on the page either (I haven't looked in the edits, so it might have been there in the past and been corrected).

In fact example 5.3 in Franklin's classic [paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm61/fm6115.pdf) has an example of a countable, compact, sequential space $M_1$ that has unique sequential limits but which is **not** Hausdorff. So $M_1$ is not sequentially Hausdorff, trivially (as for it, $\tau=\bar{\tau}$, being sequential).

So fix your idea of sequentially Hausdorff means. Your initial claim is false as it stands.. But it's true by definition with the correct definition.

Comment: Thank you for pulling me out of this dead end. Guess that's just another inconsistency among Wikipedia pages. The disagreement occurs at section "Definition"-"Preliminaries", which it says: "a space in which every sequence converges to at most one point is called a sequentially Hausdorff space"

Comment: @mcxzx I say, fix it, to avoid confusion. The Franklin paper is even among the references (he defined sequential spaces in the first place..)

Comment: @mcxzx I couldn't find a good reference for US spaces. There is a paper (by Wilansky) "between $T_1$ and $T_2$ spaces" (or a title close to it) where he defined US = unique sequential limit (so $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to y$ implies $x=y$ always)  and KC=compact subsets of $X$ are closed. He shows that $T_2 \implies$  KC $ \implies$ US $\implies T_1$ and that none are reversible. They're pretty obscure otherwise (not mentioned in the Wikipedia page on separation axioms). So the internal link on your page is inconsistent: they say one thing but the link states the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

For sequential spaces, having every sequence converge to at most one point is equivalent to the fact that the diagonal $\{(x,x)| x \in X \}$ is sequentially closed in the product $X \times_{seq} X$. Note that this is the product in the category of sequential spaces SeqTop, not the product in Top.

However, every sequential space is compactly generated, and the product in SeqTop is the same as the product in the category of compactly generated spaces. So the notion of being closed is equivalent to being k-closed, and the condition that every sequence in the sequential topology converges to at most one point is equivalent to the sequential topology being [weakly Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Hausdorff_space), which is weaker but arguably more natural than it being Hausdorff.

Being weakly Hausdorff (and hausdorff-compactly generated, which sequential spaces are) is a much nicer property than being Hausdorff, since the category of [weakly hausdorff hausdorff-compactly generated spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_compactly_generated_weak_Hausdorff_spaces) is very well behaved. And it turns out to include all "sequentially haussdorff" (weak form) (sub)sequential spaces.